# How can I Listview to fit?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView which contains ImageView, TextView and Checkbox but,
When textView is long, checkBox is almost unavailable. I want to ListView to fit for a line.

How can I solve a problem that I have mentioned in the image?

ROW

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newImage"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:saveEnabled="false" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/newTaskTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="78.57" />

    <CheckBox

        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="18.45"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="@string/checkBox" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

LISTVIEW

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="203dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />
```

[image: LISTVIEW TO FIT PROBLEM (image)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Imageview` width is already defined, So we should deal with 2 views and one should always be at right, and middle text to be flexible, so we can give weight to `textview` it will work fine.

You can try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/newImage"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
            android:saveEnabled="false"/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/newTaskTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="sdfsdfs"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <CheckBox

            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="checkBox"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are Welcome Friend :)